# Qt: Compare QVariable with Enum of DLL

Tags: qt

I try to compare a QVariable of a QSignalSpy with a Enum in a test function. I found `Q_ENUM_NS`, but I got a linker error. I have rebuilt it and run qmake.

Error Message: `Undefined reference to CCS::staticMetaObject`

testopcua.cpp (most parts)

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CCS::DataManagerState)

using namespace ::testing;
class TestOpcUa : public Test
{
public:
    TestOpcUa()
    {
        //.....
    }

    ~TestOpcUa()
    {
        delete _selectedConfValid;
        delete _opcUaObjectValid;
    }

protected:
    MockOpcConf* _selectedConfValid = nullptr;
    OpcUa* _opcUaObjectValid = nullptr;
};

TEST_F(TestOpcUa, checkHandshake)
{
    qRegisterMetaType<CCS::DataManagerState>("state");
    QSignalSpy readySpy(_opcUaObjectValid, SIGNAL(newManagerState(CCS::DataManagerState)));
    _opcUaObjectValid->connect();
    readySpy.wait();
    ASSERT_EQ(readySpy.count(), 1);
    ASSERT_EQ(readySpy.at(0).at(0).value<CCS::DataManagerState>(), CCS::DataManagerState::Ready); //Linker error
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

enums.h of DLL

```
#include <QObject>

namespace CCS
{
    Q_NAMESPACE

    enum class DataManagerState
    {None, Configure, Ready, Active, Waiting, Stop};
    Q_ENUM_NS(DataManagerState)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add an explicit export/import directive to the QT_NAMESPACE macro.

```cpp
namespace CCS
{
    Q_DECL_EXPORT Q_NAMESPACE

    ...
}
```

But you'll most likely need to abstract the `Q_DECL_EXPORT` part so it is a `Q_DECL_IMPORT` in right circumstances, as described in [Creating Shared Libraries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sharedlibrary.html) (or in the Qt Wiki [How to create a library with Qt...](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application))

global.h of DLL

```cpp
#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>

#if defined(MYSHAREDLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

enums.h of DLL

```cpp
#include "global.h"
#include <QObject>

namespace CCS
{
    MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT Q_NAMESPACE

    ...
}
```

Note that if you plan to also use the "DLL" code as a statically linked lib (or directly included in other code, w/out any lib), you'll need a 3rd condition in `global.h` which defines `MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT` as nothing.

global.h of DLL

```cpp
#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>

#if defined(MYSHAREDLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#elif defined(MYSHAREDLIB_STATIC)
#  define MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

---

> Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CCS::DataManagerState)

Shouldn't need this.

Answer (score 0):

Since Qt 5.14 you can use Q_NAMESPACE_EXPORT macro.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_NAMESPACE_EXPORT

```
namespace CSS
{
    Q_NAMESPACE_EXPORT(MYSHAREDLIB_LIBRARY)
    
    ...
}
```